# Javadoc using Eclipse

Tags: java, javadoc

Perhaps you can help I am busy doing a course that requires a Javadoc. I know how to make one but for some or other reason all the private methods and method detail section are not listed in the document.

Here is the code. I've included the private methods and not all code. StackExchange shouted at me. Haha

```
    /**
     * This method adds a bird to the ArrayList
     * @param listBird brings the ArrayList into the method
     */ 
    private static void addToArray(ArrayList<String> listBird)
    {
    ... 
    }
    /**
     * This method removes a bird to the ArrayList
     * @param listBird brings the ArrayList into the method
     */ 
    private static void deleteEntry(ArrayList<String> listBird)
    {
        ...
    }
    /**
     * This method displays the items within the ArrayList
     * @param listBird brings the ArrayList into the method
     */         
    private static void displayArray(ArrayList<String> listBird)
    {
        ...
     }
    /**
     * This method uses binary search to find an item within the array
     * @param listBird brings the ArrayList into the method
     */ 
    private static void searchArray(ArrayList<String> listBird)
    {
        String searchValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a bird name to search for");
        int start, mid, end, returnValue;
        returnValue = -1;
        ..................
```

Comment: Use the `-private` parameter [as documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javadoc.htm#GUID-9D532574-1CDB-4D30-99F3-A308DCAEE55F__GUID-EA2296CF-30D2-43BE-BC28-27C5F3208636)

Answer (score 2):

Nor will you, the [javadoc Tool Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) says (in part)

> documented classes
>
> The classes and interfaces for which detailed documentation is generated during a javadoc run. To be documented, the source files must be available, their source filenames or package names must be passed into the javadoc command, and they must not be filtered out by their [access modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#public) (public, protected, package-private or private). We also refer to these as the classes included in the javadoc output, or the included classes.

**tl;dr** run [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#public) with

```
-private
```

For [eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/compiler/ref-preferences-javadoc.htm?resultof=%22%6a%61%76%61%64%6f%63%22%20) (from the link) you *Indicate your preferences for the Javadoc settings on the  Opens the Javadoc preference page `Java > Compiler > Javadoc` preference page.*

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped, so appreciated!